# Setting drive letter affects other disk

Tags: powershell, uefi, vhd

I have attached VHD with diskpart, disk number is `2`. `$drive_ltrs = (get-partition -disknumber 2).driveletter` returns `D`. If now I assign `W` to the EFI partition, `D` gets deleted. Why is this happening?

```
${vol_letter_efi} = get-partition | where-object {$_.GptType -eq "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"} | select-object -first 1 DriveLetter
${vol_letter_efi} = ${vol_letter_efi}.DriveLetter
if([string]${vol_letter_efi} -eq ""){
    ${vol_letter_efi} = get_efi_partition_letter %just returns W
    $part_nr_efi = get-partition | where-object {$_.GptType -eq "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"} | select-object -first 1 PartitionNumber
    $part_nr_efi = $part_nr_efi.PartitionNumber
    Get-Partition -PartitionNumber $part_nr_efi | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter ${vol_letter_efi}
}
```